# File can find the file but FileReader can't

Tags: java, file, filereader

I am trying to read a .txt file in java.
I placed the file in the root folder of the project.

When I do this:

```java
URL url = getClass().getResource("/test.txt");
System.out.println(url);
File file = new File(url.getPath());
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

I get the correct path back.
But when i want to use the File in a FileReader it can't find the file.

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)));
```

Even when I place a test file on my desktop and use a absolut path the FileReader can't find the file.

I don't know what to do, I have tried a lot of stuff.

Can someone help me.

Comment: `File` represents an abstract path, and can easily represent an invalid path. You would need to use `File.canRead()` to validate that `File` actually can find something there.

Comment: When i do file.canRead() i get true

Comment: getClass().getResource() is only for files present in the classpath. Usually the root directory is not in the classpath. And you should keep in mind that the classpath can be different for develpment (IDE under src) and production (inside a JAR or WAR). For a file not in the classpath you should use normal absolute or relative file paths. It is also recommended to use the new NIO interface Path instead of File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources (Class.getResource) cannot generally be dealt with `File`, they are files on the class path, possibly packed in a .jar file. You can get a reader as follows:

```
new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

The above uses an InputStream of the resource. As you know the Charset of the file, specify it for a Reader.

That it worked was a working directory issue in combination with your IDE's settings.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to try here:

1. Use the full path instead of using a relative path use the full path e.g. something like `"/Users/BlueDragon709/Desktop/test.txt"` instead of `"/test.txt"`
2. If that fails check the file permissions.

When you are currently using File you aren't attempting to access it until you instantiate the Scanner so it not going to fail until you hit that line of code.